# Testing Docusign Connect locally

Tags: docusignapi

I've read that to use Docusign Connect, you must point the service to a public facing URL which uses SSL and a valid, purchased certificate.

Is it possible, using demo.docusign.net, to test Docusign Connect locally? I'd like to test out all of the various envelope/recipient events without having to publish (and re-publish) my changes to a public site each time I need to make a change.

**More info:**
I am using ASP.NET Web API for my Docusign Connect "listener". I was hoping to be able to somehow point Docusign Connect to my local site so that I can step through the code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to leverage the built in logging, which will include the XML payload, but will not include the PDF Bytes. In the Connect configuration, ensure you have Enable Log (maximum 100) enabled. Then under account->preferences->Connect, there are 2 links for Logs and Failures.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still relevant and this may be useful for future DocuSign devs. DocuSign suggests using https://webhook.site for "replaying webhook messages with Postman". This is their article on how to use it: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/replaying-webhook-messages-postman

In case the URL is dead, here is the relevant part:

> [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) can be used to mimic the notifications received from DocuSign.
> Since Postman runs on your development machine, it can also make HTTP
> or HTTPS calls to your application running on localhost.
>
> To send messages with Postman, first use [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) to record a
> notification from DocuSign and then export the received notification
> message as CURL instructions:
>
> 1. Go to webhook.site to get a unique URL that you’ll use as the
>    destination URL for your webhook.
> 2. Using the DocuSign eSignature Admin
>    (settings) tool, set your webhook to use the URL from step 1 for your
>    webhook.
> 3. Configure the event triggers, such as “Envelope Send,” that
>    you want to test.
> 4. Create and send an envelope.
> 5. On the webhook.site
>    dashboard, you will see your incoming webhook notification messages.
>
> (at this point I just copy and pasted the response but DocuSign gives the following directions for exporting/importing
>
> 6. Click export as and select curl.
> 7. Open your Postman application and import the exported Curl script by selecting File > Import > Raw Text and paste the Curl script.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status of an envelope in the Connect XML format using the SOAP API:

https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?op=GetStatusInDocuSignConnectFormat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free level of service from Heroku to test your listener if your stack is available from them.

For an example of this, see the [WebHook recipe on the DocuSign DevCenter](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status).

For the ASP.NET stack, you can you use the free level of service from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free server certificate from [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). You do not need a purchased certificate. You cannot use a self-signed certificate.